# Issue while creating image slideshow video using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm trying to create an image slideshow video post on a facebook page with facebook graph api.

```
slideshow_spec={
     "images_urls":[
       "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hads-xtf1/t45.1600-4/11410027_6032434826375_425068598_n.png",
       "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hads-xtp1/t45.1600-4/11410105_6031519058975_1161644941_n.png",
       "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/parody/images/2/27/Minions_bob_and_his_teddy_bear_2.jpg"
     ],
     "duration_ms": 2000,`
     "transition_ms": 200
   }'
-F 'access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.7/<PAGE_ID>/videos"
```

This is the URL i have constructed but i'm getting html code as response. Couldn't find out what's the issue.Can anyone help me out? When i trigger this URL from browser by adding &method=POST its getting posted but when i make a connection from java end i'm getting this issue.I have tried by encoding the parameters also but no use.

Thanks